# std::function template argument resolution

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std-function

I am currently working on a library where I am chaining function objects.

I am creating a function template that takes a callable object (std::function at the moment) and is parametrized on the output and input type of the function. Here is a simplified version of what I am defining:

```
template <typename In, typename Out>
std::vector<Out> process(std::vector<In> vals, std::function< Out(In) > func)
{
    // apply func for each value in vals
    return result;
}
```

The problem I am having is on usage. It seems that when I pass a lambda, the compiler cannot deduce the type correctly, so complains that the function doesn't exist:

```
std::vector<string> strings;
// does NOT compile
auto chars = process(strings,
        []( std::string s ) -> char
        {
            return s[0]; // return first char
        }
);
```

If I explicitly wrap the lambda in `std::function`, the program compiles:

```
std::vector<string> strings;
// DOES compile
auto chars = process(strings,
        std::function< char(std::string) >(
        []( std::string s ) -> char
        {
            return s[0]; // return first char
        })
);
```

I haven't tested passing function pointers or function objects yet, but it seems like it will be difficult for the compiler to deduce the the `In` and `Out` parameters if I'm not directly passing the explicit `std::function` object.

My question is this: is there a way to get around this, so that I can deduce the input/return type of a callable object without explicitly mentioning them at the call site?

Perhaps parametrize the template on the function type instead of the input/return types? Essentially I need to deduce the `In` and `Out` type for an arbitrary callable. Perhaps some kind of `auto`/`decltype` trick for the return type of the template function?

Thank you.

Comment: It's just an example of course, but this is exactly what `std::transform` does.

Comment: yes I am fully aware of that. Transform works on iterators but I need to create another object parametrized on the return type of the transformation. As far as I am aware, transform doesn't need those types as it can just do `*out = *in++; ++out;` without ever knowing the value_types as it just deals with the iterators. The example simplifies things quite a bit- the requirement is knowledge of the input/return type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you can do is to create an intermediate return type deducing function which uses `decltype` to determine the arguments to be passed to the actual function object:

```
template <typename Out, typename In>
std::vector<Out> process_intern(std::vector<In> vals, std::function< Out(In) > func)
{
    // whatever
}

template <typename In, typename Func>
auto process(std::vector<In> vals, Func func) -> std::vector<decltype(func(vals[0]))>
{
    return process_intern<decltype(func(vals[0]))>(vals, func);
}
```

Of course, you may want to consider implementing the logic in `process()` directly anyway unless there is a reason to type erase the function type.

Comment: Cool! You raise a good point about type erasure, I don't think I need it. Neat trick to get the return type, thanks!

Comment: The compiler somehow figures out that `decltype(func(vals[0]))` maps to the parameter list of `template<typename Out, typename In> process_intern`. I was unaware that the compiler could deduce template arguments from a non-trivial `decltype` expression in this fashion. A surprising trick.

Comment: @damienh: All `decltype(func(vals[0]))` does is finding the return type of a `func(vals[0])`. The resulting type is, however, explicitly specified when calling `process_intern()`.

Answer (score 8):

> is there a way to get around this, so that I can deduce the input/return type of a callable object without explicitly mentioning them at the call site?

No. User-defined conversions are not considered in template argument deduction. The compiler have to come up with `In` and `Out` such that the type of the parameter and the type of the argument have to match (almost) exactly, but they never will in this case.

> Perhaps parametrize the template on the function type instead of the input/return types

Yes, that's what is normally done (take a look at the standard library algorithms, for example)

Comment: Thanks, the stuff about user-defined conversions makes sense.