# Template function substitution works only if one isn't using std::function in one parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a template function with two template parameters.

The first (`T`) is deduced based on the type of the first parameter past to the function. The second (`ItrT`) is deduced by use of `std::type_traits` and `T`.

When I use `ItrT` as the type for a parameter (see function `bar`) than all types are deduced implicitly, but when I use `std::function<void(ItrT)>` as the type of a parameter (see function `foo`) than the correct types can only be deduced when fully specifying all template parameter(Even if using the exact same code as in the function definition). One would imagine that using `ItrT` inside a template wouldn't change the compilers ability to deduce the template.

Why isn't this the case? And what do I need to do, so that all template parameter can be implicitly deduced?

I'm using C++17.

```
template <class T, class ItrT = typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>
auto foo(T iterator, std::function<void(ItrT)> expr) -> void{
}

template <class T, class ItrT = typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>
auto bar(T iterator, ItrT expr) -> void{
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3};

    bar(vec.begin(), 1); // Compiles!

    foo(vec.begin(), [](int) {}); // Failes!

    foo<decltype(vec.begin()),
        std::iterator_traits<decltype(vec.begin())>::value_type>
        (vec.begin(), [](int) {}); // Compiles!
}
```

Comment: lambda are not `std::function`.

Comment: Btw, in second case, `ItrT` is deduced base on parameter, not default template type.

Comment: Related to [stdfunction-template-argument-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753801/stdfunction-template-argument-resolution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the confusion here is around the role of default template arguments.

The rule is not: try to deduce a parameter. If deduction fails, then use the default (if provided).

Rather, the rule is: if the parameter is in a deduced context, deduce it. If deduction fails, abort. If it's not in a deduced context, and it's not explicitly provided, use the default argument. In other words, the default argument is used only if the parameter is neither in a deduced context nor explicitly provided.

In both your examples, `ItrT` is in a deduced context, so the default template argument is not considered at all. The difference between the two is that you *can* deduce `T` from a lambda (you just match its type) but you *cannot* deduce `function<void(T)` from a lambda - a lambda can be *converted* to an appropriate `function`, but a lambda *is not* a `function`. Template deduction doesn't do conversions. Template deduction just matches patterns.